# New market battery says No "Fully Charged"

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging, power, system-information

I have a Macbook Pro Retina that I bought brand new in 2015. Its battery died and wouldn't boot. Because it's old, Apple wouldn't provide a battery in my country, so the shop bought a battery "from the market" and replaced the old one.

In System Information -> Hardware -> Power -> Battery Information, I get:

Battery Information:

```
Model Information:
  Serial Number:    C01514309YEF90MA4
  Manufacturer: SMP
  Device Name:  bq20z451
  Pack Lot Code:    3230
  PCB Lot Code: 3230
  Firmware Version: 2d31
  Hardware Revision:    322d
  Cell Revision:    3036
Charge Information:
  Fully Charged:    No         <---- Here!
  Charging: Yes
  Full Charge Capacity (mAh):   9054
  State of Charge (%):  100
Health Information:
  Cycle Count:  1
  Condition:    Normal
```

It says not fully charged, although the state of charge is at 100%. In contrast, hovering over the battery icon says fully charged, and the charger's light is green. Should I worry about it? I don't know what the old authentic battery reported.

[image]

Comment: You should really judge the battery by how it performs.

Comment: Did you reset the SMC/Pram

Comment: iFixit have a battery recalibration page. I honesty don't know whether it's really needed any more [& certainly not once a month] but after you reset the SMC ↑ it might be worth trying *once*. https://www.ifixit.com/Wiki/Battery_Calibration

Comment: @Ruskes I don't know what the repair lab did; I didn't do anything. Not sure what SMC and Pram are, which one should I reset? I guess by following this guide https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8642800. nenwiggy new battery was installed yesterday. Noted Tetsujin.

Comment: Google reset SMC on Mac. SMC System Management Control, it manages Battery

Comment: Thank you @Ruskes. Luckily I didn't do anything and the problem fixed itself!

Comment: The battery management system probably just needed some time to understand the new battery. By using the battery it re-calibrated automatically. Glad it's working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Without me doing anything**,

since I didn't use the laptop, but had it charging, now I can see via the system information, that "Fully charged" is set to "Yes", and "Charging" to "No".

---

*If* doing nothing didn't work for you, then I refer you to the comments under my question:

- Did you reset the SMC/Pram. Google reset SMC on Mac. SMC System
  Management Control, it manages Battery – Ruskes
- iFixit have a battery
  recalibration page. I honesty don't know whether it's really needed
  any more [& certainly not once a month] but after you reset the SMC ↑
  it might be worth trying once. ifixit.com/Wiki/Battery_Calibration –
  Tetsujin